# Get AVG(Price) using 3 SQL Tables

Tags: sql-server, join, average

I want the average price each Category, where the products are grouped in categories thru the Product_Category_Mapping table.

The Product Table has ID and Price columns and I want the average price for all the Products for each Category.

```
Product Table: 
ID, 
Name, 
Price

Category Table: 
ID, 
Name

Product_Category_Mapping Table: 
ID, 
CategoryID, 
ProductID
```

Any ideas??

Comment: any reason you haven't shown an attempt?

Comment: Yeah, why not just give an effort to write your own query then ask what is missing or problem with your query

Comment: Wow ... nice comments Edrich, yes - I did make a couple attempts and they did not work and adding them to the question would have just muddied the waters - nice, real nice comment and ever so helpful

Answer (score 0):

you just need to understand join in sqlserver. Here we use innerjoin for the one to one relationship.

```
declare @Category Table(ID int, Name varchar(50))
declare @Product Table(ID int, Name varchar(50), Price int)

declare @Product_Category_Mapping Table (ID int, CategoryID int, ProductID int)

insert into @Category values (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')
insert into @Product values (1,'p1',10),(2,'p2',20),(3,'p3',30)
insert into @Product_Category_Mapping values (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,2,3)

select 
    c.id, avg(price)
from @Product_Category_Mapping pcm 
    inner join @Product p on p.id = pcm.ProductID
    inner join @Category c on c.id = pcm.CategoryID

group by c.id
```

**Updated**

As your comment, I understand and I update the some code as below. Tell me if you an issue.

```
declare @Product Table(ID int, Name varchar(50), Price int)

declare @Product_Category_Mapping Table (ID int, CategoryID int, ProductID int)

insert into @Category values (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')
insert into @Product values (1,'p1',10),(2,'p2',20),(3,'p3',30)
insert into @Product_Category_Mapping values (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,2,3)

select --Category.[name] as CatName, Product.[Id], Product.[Name], [Price] 
    c.id, 
    c.Name,
    p.ID,
    p.Name,
    avg(isnull(price,0)) over(partition by c.id ) as avgprice
from @Category c    
    left join @Product_Category_Mapping pcm  on c.id = pcm.CategoryID
    left join @Product p on p.id = pcm.ProductID
```

Comment: I tried this and can't fig out why it's not binding:  SELECT Category.[name] as CatName, Product.[Id], Product.[Name], [Price]
 
  FROM  [Category] join Product_Category_Mapping as map on map.CategoryId = Category.id 
  join Product as Prod on map.ProductID = Product.[Id] .....Thanks for your reply and sample!

Comment: it's not binding means. and what is the issue you face. I checked your code. Why the product portion u introduce in query. You need category avg price, so how does product comes or just want to show the all product with avg category price?